# window.onload get something wrong

Tags: javascript, php

I got information from others' api,but I could not take it out,so I write it in a input.

```
 for(var x=0;x< loc.length;x++){
       point[x]=new window.BMap.Point(loc[x].lat, loc[x].lng);
       getloc(point[x],x);    
      }

     function getloc(pt,i){
        gc.getLocation(pt, function(rs){
         var addComp = rs.addressComponents;
         var dd= addComp.city + "" + addComp.district + "" + addComp.street;
         var addname="address"+i;
         var text="<input type='hidden' value="+dd+" name="+addname+" />";
         $(".page-container").append(text);
         });
      }
```

Then problems happened.

here is my window.load

```
     window.onload=function(){
var container_1_set={
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'sudden turn'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'sudden turn times'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
          enabled:false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br>'+
                    'count: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                cursor:'pointer',
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                },
                point:{
                    events:{
                        click:function(){
                                location.href="road_list.php?road="+this.category;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'sudden turn',
            data: [  <?php foreach ($result["data"] as $item) {?>
                {
                y:<?php echo $item["time"];?>,
                color:"<?php echo $item["color"];?>",
                },
                <?php }
?>]
        }]
    };

    var cat=[];
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
        var aa=$("input[name='address"+i+"']").val();
        cat.push(aa);
    }
    console.log(cat);
    container_1_set.xAxis.categories=cat;
    $('#container_1').highcharts(container_1_set);
};
```

If I press F5 button,it can get value and work.
but when clicking on the column of the chart,the variable cat get all undefined.

Comment: You mean `$(window).load`, there is no (standard) `window.load`.

Comment: should cat array be numbers not strings? A demo of this that replicates the problem would help

Comment: It is highchart,if you have used,

Answer (score 0):

Window load is not required. Instead You already have document ready. No need to use both.